# Apache Pulsar - acknowledge from different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-pulsar

I've spun up a Pulsar Java consumer in thread *T1* and I'm handing over the messages for processing to thread *T2*.

Is it safe to acknowledge messages from *T2*? Specifically, is calling `consumer.acknowledge(messageId)` on the instance shared between two threads ok?

Comment: Good question. We would like to do a simimar setup in our project as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the java client is thread safe, so the interaction you described should be fine.

Comment: Do you have some reference? The javadoc seems rather brief and the [documentation][1] not explicit enough.

  [1]: https://pulsar.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/clients/Java/#Consumers-j8vfvs]

Comment: @MilosGregor every class in the Pulsar Java client is thread safe. We will make it more explicit in the Javadocs